# How to underline part of a heading (first 40px for instance)?

Tags: css, underline

Is it possible in simple CSS to have a heading underlined partly only, specifically first 50px on the left?

Comment: Any reason not to use a dummy element or even a styled hr tag with a fixed width ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `:before` pseudo element and add a border to it.

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
h1:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 1.2em;
  height: 0;
  width: 50px;
  content: '';
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a header, partly underlined</h1>
```

Answer (score 12):

Use a `pseudo-element`:

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
}
h1::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1>foobar</h1>
```

Comment: 10 seconds faster and even slightly better than my answer. +1

Comment: Yes, less styles used, however - similar result :) with yours you can manipulate with `border-style`, if the OP wants a "prettier effect".

Answer (score 1):

You can add a pseudo element containing a couple of non-breaking spaces that are underlined. This way you get a real underlining instead of a border. However it will still cross over letters like "g".

```css
h1::before {
  content:'\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  text-decoration:underline;
  width:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1>Headline</h1>
<h1>Another Headline</h1>
```